# Why does a single line app with System.Console.WriteLine give me a syntax error?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

I decided to have a go at building Windows Metro style apps with the Windows Developer Preview again, after multiple frustrating experiences.

So I fire up Visual Studio and BAM! Right as I try to type in this code

```
System.Console.WriteLine("");
```

it gives me the red squiggly under "Console".

So I try something else:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");
```

and THAT fails as well! Red squiggly under File.

Why is this error popping up? All this code should work fine! Or am I making a basic mistake?

Comment: There is no console and a very empty System.IO namespace for Metro-style apps. I guess what you are seeing is indeed correct.

Comment: Abel: a red, wavy underline, indicating a syntax error at the underlined position. Very common in graphical IDEs.

Comment: @Joey: oh that! Why didn't he say a red wavy underline? Sorry, non-native, and "red squiggly" was the first time I heard the term ;)

Comment: You need to set your time machine to June 2013 and imagine your Metro app running on a pad with an ARM core with an 8 hour battery life.  Whole bunch of things you can no longer do.  No console window.  And all OS calls that can block for more than a handful of milliseconds are *verboten*.  Now you know why C# version 5 will have support for the *async* keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because [Metro applications use a subset of the .Net Framework API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this version [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454070%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and `System.IO.File` do not exist.

From MSDN, *"Replace `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` method with a method that uses the asynchronous I/O members; for example:"*

```
public static async Task<string> ReadAllText(StorageFile file)
{
    IInputStream inputStream = await file.OpenForReadAsync();
    using (Stream stream = inputStream.AsStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. I guess there's no way to work around this besides just recoding everything. Thanks.

Comment: To be fair to .Net, using the `Console` makes no sense in a GUI.

Comment: Many of the things that seem like the simplest possible thing, including the classic Hello World, are anything but the simplest possible in Metro world. Put a control on your form (eg a button) and do something in the handler (but don't use a message box or write to a file.) Change the text of a label for example. That's your Hello Metro.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Metro Apps don't have a console (as the console in a graphical environment doesn't make sense), but you can get some of the functionality of the console with third party libraries like [Console Class for Metro Apps](http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/ConsoleClass/about.php)