# Can not find Console in Visual Studio 11 developer preview

Tags: c#, windows, console, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does a single line app with System.Console.WriteLine give me a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882628/why-does-a-single-line-app-with-system-console-writeline-give-me-a-syntax-error)

The environment I am having: Win 8 developer preview + Visual Studio 11 express running on Parallel Mac.

This is what I have for creating a C# class library, it's reporting can not find `Console`. Below is the source code that can easily produce the error:

```
using System;

namespace NameSpace1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are in NameSpace1.MyClass");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: posted code will not compile as is. (missing return)

Comment: why you would want to write to the console from a class library is another matter...

Comment: Thanks @Mitch Wheat. This is pure a test code to test why can not find Console in a class library. It shall be together with .NET framework.

Comment: Adding return does not fix this. still look for answers

Answer (score 1):

Well, correct me if I'm wrong but Metro Apps don't not use the full .NET library, and hence some classes are missing. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s the introduction Microsoft gives about this issue.